# Hover on element within anchor tag without selecting anchor tag. JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify

I am working on a Shopify theme where I need to select the product price & hover on it for tooltip. but the problem is those products all are within an anchor tag. I've tried to find a solution but there's not much info about it. Tried pointer-event: none; but this causes anchor not working anymore. I need the anchor tag to work & at the same time, I need the hover effect on price without selecting the anchor tag because that anchor tag is within a theme & selecting that will cause problems for different themes. SO I've made a Codepen simulation for it. check below & let me know if it is possible with CSS or js doesn't matter. Thank you.

I want to hover this box 
[image]

```css
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.price-group {
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/90946/pexels-photo-90946.jpeg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, alias.
    </p>
    <div class="price-group">
      <span class="title">Sample Product</span>
      <span class="price">$100</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: you will need javascript with [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) or you render "better" HTML. How will your markup look like when you have multiple prices? What happens if you select one, will it redirect to somewhere?

Comment: The hover state simply "bubbles up", you can not technically hover an element without hovering its parent at the same time. And the parent's parent. And so on. Hover over a link nested a dozen levels down - and you _will_ be hovering body, and html, at the same time. And this is based on DOM position, not even visual position on the screen. You could have a link that sits in your footer in the DOM, but you have it positioned fixed at the very top of your screen - hover that link, and you are still hovering your footer, at the opposite end of the screen, at the same time.

Comment: Is it possible to click instead of hover?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to be able to click the price without triggering the anchor, while not losing the functionality of the anchor.

This can be done with use `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`

You can sort of 'mask' the hovering of anchor, by overwriting the hover actions of anchor.(bad UX though)

```js
function check(event) {
  // prevent acheck or other functions of anchor 
  event.stopPropagation();
  // stops href redirection
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('inner')
}

function acheck(event) {
  console.log('anchor')
}
```

```css
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.price-group {
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.price-group:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="card" onclick='acheck(event)'>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/90946/pexels-photo-90946.jpeg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, alias.
    </p>
    <div class="price-group" onclick='check(event)'>
      <span class="title">Sample Product</span>
      <span class="price">$100</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```